# How to solve -replace was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am running a command in batch file and getting this error `-replace was unexpected at this time`

This is what I am running

```
if %ENVIRONMENT% == NEWQA (
powershell '(Get-Content Identity-Authority.CrudTests\\\\\\App.config) -replace " int ", " newqa " ^| Out-File -encoding ASCII Identity-Authority.CrudTests\\\\\\App.config'

)
```

I have tried escaping with `^-replace`, using `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` in the script and nothing works. When I echo the variable it is not empty.

Please help!

Comment: Why don't you just use the correct quoting? Everything for `powershell` to run should be enclosed in doublequotes, then everything you'd normally type in powershell is used in exactly the same way as you would in PowerShell itself. Then once you've done that you need to adjust some of that nested code, escape any doublequotes it has, with a backslash, and any percent character with another percent character.`%`. I don't know what all of those concurrent backslashes are for or how many there are supposed to be, so I cannot advise you on how many of those may need adjusting, if any.

Comment: I'd suggest, for example: `If /I "%ENVIRONMENT%" == "NEWQA" (powershell.exe "(Get-Content Identity-Authority.CrudTests\\\\\\App.config) -replace ' int ', ' newqa ' | Out-File -encoding ASCII Identity-Authority.CrudTests\\\\\\App.config")`. Or `If /I "%ENVIRONMENT%" == "NEWQA" (powershell.exe "(Get-Content Identity-Authority.CrudTests\\\\\\App.config) -replace \" int \", \" newqa \" | Out-File -encoding ASCII Identity-Authority.CrudTests\\\\\\App.config")`.

Comment: What made you believe the `SETLOCAL` options would help you?

Comment: Shammir, it has been well over three days since your question was posted, an answer added, and my comments above submitted. Can you please act responsibly, as a not new member of this site, and provide appropriate feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
... App.config) - ...
```

should be

```
... App.config^) - ...
```

This tells `cmd` that the `)` is part of the `powershell` command, not closing the `if [true]` command.